# Stacking SVGs and animation

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg, svg-animate

I am still learning a lot of coding, but I have been confused looking into SVG stacking etc.

I am trying to create a graphic of a computer, with all its parts, that can animate to show the parts separate. Now would it be easier to create one SVG file with all the layers required and animate the layers separately, or to use already separated files and place them on top of each other?

I have them in separate files currently, and every time I look up how to stack them in the same location, I get tutorials on how to stack them in one file and spread them to different locations on the site, the exact opposite of what I want to do.

I don't really have any code to display because I'm unsure how I should load the SVGs into the html if I want them to stack on top of each other. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at absolute positions in CSS. You can find information on positioning in CSS here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

I suggest wrapping the images with a div that is set to `position: relative` and making the images themselves `position: absolute`. That way, they will stack ontop of each other.

To ensure the proper stack order, you can make use of the `z-index` CSS property.

Once you have your layout set up, you can use JavaScript (I'd recommend using JQuery but it can be achieved with regular JavaScript as well) to dynamically show and hide each single image.

Comment: I have not looked into animating SVG files yet so unfortunately I can't tell which would be easier but if you want seperate files, my suggestion would be a way to do it.